# Почему при введении числа большего чем 18446744073709551615 выполняется ветка if, если там стоит условие <=?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(void)
{
   unsigned long long n;
   int i, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9;
   puts("Input number");
   scanf_s("%llu", &n);
   a0 = 0, a1 = 0, a2 = 0, a3 = 0, a4 = 0, a5 = 0, a6 = 0, a7 = 0, a8 = 0, a9 = 0;
   if (n <= 18446744073709551615)
   {
       while (n > 0)
       {
           i = n % 10;
           switch (i)
           {
           case 1:a1 = a1 + 1; break;
           case 2:a2 = a2 + 1; break;
           case 3:a3 = a3 + 1; break;
           case 4:a4 = a4 + 1; break;
           case 5:a5 = a5 + 1; break;
           case 6:a6 = a6 + 1; break;
           case 7:a7 = a7 + 1; break;
           case 8:a8 = a8 + 1; break;
           case 9:a9 = a9 + 1; break;
           case 0:a0 = a0 + 1; break;
           }
           n = n / 10;
       }
       printf("1-%d,2-%d,3-%d,4-%d,5-%d,6-%d,7-%d,8-%d,9-%d,0-%d \n", a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a0);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Error");
   }
   system("pause");
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Не как ответ на вопрос, а просто подсказка... Вместо 10 переменных a0 - a9 можно использовать один массив из 10 элементов и увеличивать его элементы **по индексу**, а не через switch (программа сократится в 10 раз)

Comment: Прежде, чем задавать вопрос, следовало прочитать предупреждения компилятора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых: прошу, никогда не юзайте магические числа. Что оно значит, как понять? В данном контексте, думаю, это uint64max, тогда, очевидно, что вы зайдёте в эту ветку, т.к uint64max <= uint64max. Больше него нет числа в пределах 64 бит, вот и заходите.

Так же, старайтесь сразу инициализировать переменные.

```
int a0 = 0...
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `unsigned long long` не может быть больше 18446744073709551615 и по факту в `n` сохраняется меньшее число. Можете вывести на экран и посмотреть.